# Add class to variable inside echo

Tags: php, css

How can i add  to variable $title inside echo ? In the foreach:

```
<?php 
        foreach($this->searchfields as $fsearch) {
            $title = $this->field->showFieldTitle($this->catid,$fsearch);
            echo "<div id=".$fsearch->name.">".htmlspecialchars($title)."";
            $this->field->showFieldSearch($fsearch,$this->catid,null);
            echo "</div>";
        }?>
```

I tried `echo "<div id=".$fsearch->name.">".htmlspecialchars(<div class="header">$title</div>)."";` but it doesnt work :)

Comment: The way you have put in your question should work, what is it doing now? Any errors?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: You have blatant syntax errors in your PHP code. You absolutely need to enable full error reporting in your development box. Please ask for advice if you don't know how but don't keep on coding blindly.

Comment: That can't be from this code. That must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
echo "<div id='".$fsearch->name."'><div class='header'>".htmlspecialchars($title)."</div>";
```

?

Comment: You're most welcome! Please mark this answer as 'accepted' if it was of use. I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Done, but i cant add +1 - low carma :)